# How to find total booked time between 08:00-16:00 on a resource

Tags: mysql, datetime

Trying to find the total time a resource is booked between two timestamps a day -Let's say 08:00 - 16:00.

So far I came up with this solution but it's not working as intended. I know why it's not working but I'm not sure how I get from here to a working SQL.

```
SELECT bookingresource.resourceID, SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(booking.bookingEndDatetime) - TIME_TO_SEC(booking.bookingStartDatetime))) AS totalTimeBooked 
FROM booking, bookingresource 
WHERE booking.bookingID =  bookingresource.bookingID
AND bookingresource.bookingStartDatetime BETWEEN '2019-03-11 00:00:00' AND '2019-03-11 23:59:59'
AND HOUR(bookingresource.bookingStartDatetime) BETWEEN 8 AND 16 
AND HOUR(bookingresource.bookingEndDatetime) BETWEEN 8 AND 16
AND booking.companyID = 2447 AND bookingresource.`resourceID` = 807
GROUP BY bookingresource.resourceID
```

By doing it this way I don't include the bookings that start or end outside of 8-16 which is not intended. How do I include bookings that have part of their booking time in between 08:00-16:00 and only calculate the time booked within 08:00 - 16:00.

EDIT: I will try to simplify the SQL a bit, so there isn't so much unnecessary code. My issue is now with the way the total time is calculated. At the moment it will include times outside the time range if the booking is partly inside the time range.

```
SELECT bookingresource.resourceID, SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(booking.bookingEndDatetime) - TIME_TO_SEC(booking.bookingStartDatetime))) AS timediff FROM booking, bookingresource 
WHERE booking.bookingID =  bookingresource.bookingID
AND (HOUR(bookingresource.bookingStartDatetime) BETWEEN 8 AND 16 
OR HOUR(bookingresource.bookingEndDatetime) BETWEEN 8 AND 16)
GROUP BY bookingresource.resourceID
```

EDIT 2: So I found a solution but I have a problem with bookings that span over more than one day. This my solution so far:

```
SELECT bookingresource.resourceID, SEC_TO_TIME(sum(LEAST(TIME_TO_SEC(TIME(booking.bookingEndDatetime)), TIME_TO_SEC('16:00')) - GREATEST(TIME_TO_SEC(TIME(booking.bookingStartDatetime)), TIME_TO_SEC('08:00')))) AS totalTimeBooked FROM booking, bookingresource 
WHERE booking.bookingID =  bookingresource.bookingID
AND bookingresource.bookingStartDatetime BETWEEN '2019-04-10 00:00:00' AND '2019-04-10 23:59:59'
AND (TIME(bookingresource.bookingStartDatetime) BETWEEN '08:00' AND '16:00' 
OR TIME(bookingresource.bookingEndDatetime) BETWEEN '08:00' AND '16:00')
  AND bookingresource.`resourceID` = 453
  group by bookingresource.resourceID
```

Comment: `... AND (HOUR BETWEEN OR HOUR BETWEEN)`.  Either starts **or** ends in your time range.

Comment: Thank you but this will only fix my inclusion problem but will not fix the number of hours the resource is booked within the time range.

Comment: Use `MAX` and `MIN` to calculate your "limited" start and end times.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean here. How would you go about doing that?

Answer (score 0):

Try convert you string date in proper datetime value

and if you don't want values  outside the range 8 - 16 then you should also check that the date for star and end is the same

```
  SELECT bookingresource.resourceID
    , SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(booking.bookingEndDatetime) - TIME_TO_SEC(booking.bookingStartDatetime))) AS totalTimeBooked 
  FROM booking
  INNER JOIN  bookingresource  ON booking.bookingID =  bookingresource.bookingID
  WHERE  bookingresource.bookingStartDatetime BETWEEN str_to_date('2019-03-11 00:80:00', '%Y-%m-%d %T') 
        AND str_to_date('2019-03-11 23:59:59', '%Y-%m-%d %T') 
  AND HOUR(bookingresource.bookingStartDatetime) BETWEEN 8 AND 16 
  AND HOUR(bookingresource.bookingEndDatetime) BETWEEN 8 AND 16
  AND DATE(bookingresource.bookingStartDatetime) = DATE(bookingresource.bookingEndDatetime)
  AND booking.companyID = 2447 
  AND bookingresource.`resourceID` = 807
  GROUP BY bookingresource.resourceID
```